# Read related table fields from trigger in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table visitor with fields Id,Name,MObile,EMail

& a child table VisitorHistory with fields Id,VisitorId[ForeignKey with Visitor table], Date, Purpose

I am writing a trigger against VisitorHistory , so that every new insert will logged to a different table
SO i use the below trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trigger_VisitHistory_INSERT
AFTER INSERT
   ON VisitorHistory FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE visitor_id integer;
    DECLARE visitor_name varchar(255);
    DECLARE priority integer;
    DECLARE description varchar(550);
    DECLARE activity varchar(255);
    DECLARE actionId integer;
   set @visitor_id=new.VisitorId;
   set @visitor_name=''; Is any way to get visitor_name from the related table [foreign key table]
   set @priority=1;
   set @description= concat(' USer Visited again for ',new.Purpose);
   set @activity='Revisit';
   set @actionId=new.Id;
    INSERT INTO ActivityLog (UserId,Priority,Activity,Description,ActionId) VALUES (@user_id,@priority,@activity,@description,@actionId);
END;
```

Is any way to get visitor_name from the related table  using VisitorID[foreign key table] so i can use that with description in log

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax I think

```
INSERT INTO table (UserId, Priority, Activity, Description, ActionId, name) 
SELECT @user_id, 
       @priority, 
       @activity, 
       @description, 
       @actionId,
       user.name 
FROM user 
WHERE user.id = @user_id;
```

I did not test this, but along this concept you should get it to work